# Here map does marker belong to cluster?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Maybe someone knows if it's possible to get clustered markers list. Or to know if marker is inside cluster or not. The issue is currently each marker on my map have associated polyline as well. But when two or more markers gets clustered I want to hide polylines for those markers. Would it be possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this would be to add the markers to a h.map.Group() while rendering them and then you would be able to find if the marker is part of the group as well as the proximity of the two markers. Another way is to look at this marker clustering [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/dev_guide/topics/clustering.html) to combine the markers if they are nearby.

Comment: I don't know if I got your answer wrong, or if I haven't specified clearly. I already built clustering using example you provided. The problem that I'm having is that I can't find a way to know if markers are clustered(combined) or not except seeing it on the map.